# BLE CC2541 disconnect with the app after some time

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, connectivity, disconnection

I am working on CC2541 BLE controller. I am using SimpleBLEPeripheral from TI BLE stack which is available on TI's website. I have interfaced the controller with a sensor whose state changes at an interval of 3 seconds. This means that event is generated at every 3 seconds. I am using custom profile's UUID whose length is 128 bits. I have also developed an app to get the sensor's data on my app. All is working good but device is getting disconnected with the app after establishing a connection.

I also tried changing the Connection Parameter in firmware but the issue is not resolved yet.

What should I try to make this connection flawless? I want that device should not get disconnected when it is in range and also if the device is out of range for sometime, it should auto reconnect with the app when it comes in the range of the mobile phone.

Comment: What is the connection reason that you are getting? Do you know the connection parameters that you have set on the firmware?

Comment: // Min conn interval (units of 1.25ms, 80=100ms)
#define DEFAULT_DESIRED_MIN_CONN_INTERVAL     80

// Maximum connection interval (units of 1.25ms, 800=1000ms) 
#define DEFAULT_DESIRED_MAX_CONN_INTERVAL     8000

#define DEFAULT_DESIRED_SLAVE_LATENCY         100

// (units of 10ms, 1000=10s)
#define DEFAULT_DESIRED_CONN_TIMEOUT          1000

// Whether to enable automatic parameter update request when a connection is formed
#define DEFAULT_ENABLE_UPDATE_REQUEST         TRUE

// Connection Pause Peripheral time value (in seconds)
#define DEFAULT_CONN_PAUSE_PERIPHERAL         6